# dynamic creating and mapping new field in doctrine/symfony/mysql

Tags: mysql, symfony, dynamic, doctrine, mapping

Every quartal (each 3-month) i need into table "report" add new "column" - for example "Y2014Q1" where Y=year and Q=quartal (1,2,3,4). After creating I need to make mapping of this new column in to object.

Part of my code is:

```
namespace backend\backendBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * FactSheetData
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="report")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ReportData
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Y2016Q3", type="string")
 */
private $Y2016Q3;

/**
 * @param string $Y2016Q3
 */
public function setY2016Q3($Y2016Q3)
{
    $this->Y2016Q3 = $Y2016Q3;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getY2016Q4()
{
    return $this->Y2016Q4;
}
```

....

I need to do something like this when new period comes:

```
class ReportData {

public function __construct() {
    // if new perriod alter table

    if (test_new_perriod) { 
      $new_period='Y2016Q4';
      $sql="ALTER TABLE `report` ADD COLUMN `".$new_period."` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL;";
      $stmt = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute();

      //and now - this is problem how to do - dynamic maping 
      /**
      * @var string
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="$new_period", type="string")
       */
       private $new_period;

       /**
       * @param string $new_period
       */
       public function set$new_period($new_period)
       {
       $this->$new_period =$new_period;
       }

       /**
       * @return string
       */
       public function get$new_period()
       {
       return $this->$new_period;
       }


    }
}
```

Hope I describe clear... Thanx for any advice.

Comment: I am not sure if it's a good design to add coloumn each 3 months

Comment: And how large are you going to allow your schema to grow? That is a bad design, in my opinion.

Comment: I know, but this is necesary to make on existing application - or better, this database structure will use existing application, and it is not possible to change it